# Dark tris and quads in random places when rendered with Cycles in Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, filmic-blender

I made a Mage's hat in Blender by following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/FTlvbVy8Hc8). I have finished the modelling and shading part but when I render it I got lots of dark triangles and quads on the hat. I tried fixing the normals orientation and I couldn't find an issue there. So please help me with a solution here. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Could you please be more specific? Looking at the image, nothing seems wrong, and I can't tell which dark faces you're referring to.

Comment: It looks like it's the geometry that catches shadow from the light source. If you don't want it to be like that you could try to smooth it with the smooth brush in sculpt mode

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me guys I tried it and did'nt seems to work for me,eventually I found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oecXkpAoq9U and corrected my shadow terminator and now it works fine